# Nothing is written in kannel log file

Tags: gateway, kannel

I want the log file to know to status of sms send through kannel gateway and also the connection from the smsc is bound idle or in which state. But when i tried to implement it first of all bearerbox gives an error that `fopen fails` or something like that. Then i manually created files on that location. Then it doesn't give any error and shows access file bearerbox.log and when i open these files no log is written on that file.

So I have two questions

1. How can I get the logs?
2. Is there any other way of getting status of smsc and send sms?

Thank You

Comment: this sounds like a permission issue to me.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do so. I am working on ec2 instance and using winscp software as an file explorer and i have granted all permissions to that file from its property

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
Thanks for help.
It was the silly mistake kannel log file is created on root directory automatically. It was simple but made mistake. Sorry